# Open right Content when clicking on Product

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, mysql

I'm importing and using the [Product Quick View](https://codyhouse.co/gem/css-product-quick-view/) from [codyhouse.co](http://codyhouse.co). I want to make, using this template of code, open the right content, when clicking on ".

Main problem, is that, that when I'm clicking on one content, it opens all content windows at same time. So when opening first, it opens all, and shows the last content of the product.

The content would be loaded from MySQL database, the Product_Name etc.

```
<ul class="cd-items cd-container">
    <li class="cd-item" >
        <img src="images/<?=$id;?>_1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
        <a class="cd-trigger" href="#content-<?=$row['id'];?>"><?=$row['Product_Name']?></a>
    </li> <!-- cd-item -->
</ul>    
<div class="cd-quick-view" id="content-<?=$row['id'];?>" >
    <div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
        <ul class="cd-slider">
            <li><!-- Images --></li>
        </ul> <!-- cd-slider -->
        <ul class="cd-slider-navigation">
            <li><a class="cd-next" href="#0">Prev</a></li>
            <li><a class="cd-prev" href="#0">Next</a></li>
        </ul> <!-- cd-slider-navigation -->
    </div> <!-- cd-slider-wrapper -->
    <div class="cd-item-info">
        <h2><?=$row['Product_Name']?></h2>
        <p>Price: <?=$row['price']?>USD</p>

        <ul class="cd-item-action">
            <li><button class="add-to-cart">Buy</button></li>    
        </ul> <!-- cd-item-action -->
    </div> <!-- cd-item-info -->
    <a href="#0" id="content-<?=$id?>" class="cd-close">Close</a>
</div> <!-- cd-quick-view -->
```

From the JS code, I think I should be added something, like open the right window, but have no idea, what shoud I add... :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//final width --> this is the quick view image slider width
//maxQuickWidth --> this is the max-width of the quick-view panel
var sliderFinalWidth = 400,
    maxQuickWidth = 900;

//open the quick view panel
$('.cd-trigger').on('click', function(event){
    var selectedImage = $(this).parent('.cd-item').children('img'),
        slectedImageUrl = selectedImage.attr('src');

    $('body').addClass('overlay-layer');
    animateQuickView(selectedImage, sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth, 'open');

    //update the visible slider image in the quick view panel
    //you don't need to implement/use the updateQuickView if retrieving the quick view data with ajax
    updateQuickView(slectedImageUrl);
});

//close the quick view panel
$('body').on('click', function(event){
    if( $(event.target).is('.cd-close') || $(event.target).is('body.overlay-layer')) {
        closeQuickView( sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth);
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    //check if user has pressed 'Esc'
    if(event.which=='27'){
        closeQuickView( sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth);
    }
});

//quick view slider implementation
$('.cd-quick-view').on('click', '.cd-slider-navigation a', function(){
    updateSlider($(this));
});

//center quick-view on window resize
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if($('.cd-quick-view').hasClass('is-visible')){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(resizeQuickView);
    }
});

function updateSlider(navigation) {
    var sliderConatiner = navigation.parents('.cd-slider-wrapper').find('.cd-slider'),
        activeSlider = sliderConatiner.children('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    if ( navigation.hasClass('cd-next') ) {
        ( !activeSlider.is(':last-child') ) ? activeSlider.next().addClass('selected') : sliderConatiner.children('li').eq(0).addClass('selected'); 
    } else {
        ( !activeSlider.is(':first-child') ) ? activeSlider.prev().addClass('selected') : sliderConatiner.children('li').last().addClass('selected');
    } 
}

function updateQuickView(url) {
    $('.cd-quick-view .cd-slider li').removeClass('selected').find('img[src="'+ url +'"]').parent('li').addClass('selected');
}

function resizeQuickView() {
    var quickViewLeft = ($(window).width() - $('.cd-quick-view').width())/2,
        quickViewTop = ($(window).height() - $('.cd-quick-view').height())/2;
    $('.cd-quick-view').css({
        "top": quickViewTop,
        "left": quickViewLeft,
    });
} 

function closeQuickView(finalWidth, maxQuickWidth) {
    var close = $('.cd-close'),
        activeSliderUrl = close.siblings('.cd-slider-wrapper').find('.selected img').attr('src'),
        selectedImage = $('.empty-box').find('img');
    //update the image in the gallery
    if( !$('.cd-quick-view').hasClass('velocity-animating') && $('.cd-quick-view').hasClass('add-content')) {
        selectedImage.attr('src', activeSliderUrl);
        animateQuickView(selectedImage, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth, 'close');
    } else {
        closeNoAnimation(selectedImage, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth);
    }
}

function animateQuickView(image, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth, animationType) {
    //store some image data (width, top position, ...)
    //store window data to calculate quick view panel position
    var parentListItem = image.parent('.cd-item'),
        topSelected = image.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
        leftSelected = image.offset().left,
        widthSelected = image.width(),
        heightSelected = image.height(),
        windowWidth = $(window).width(),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        finalLeft = (windowWidth - finalWidth)/2,
        finalHeight = finalWidth * heightSelected/widthSelected,
        finalTop = (windowHeight - finalHeight)/2,
        quickViewWidth = ( windowWidth * .8 < maxQuickWidth ) ? windowWidth * .8 : maxQuickWidth ,
        quickViewLeft = (windowWidth - quickViewWidth)/2;

    if( animationType == 'open') {
        //hide the image in the gallery
        parentListItem.addClass('empty-box');
        //place the quick view over the image gallery and give it the dimension of the gallery image
        $('.cd-quick-view').css({
            "top": topSelected,
            "left": leftSelected,
            "width": widthSelected,
        }).velocity({
            //animate the quick view: animate its width and center it in the viewport
            //during this animation, only the slider image is visible
            'top': finalTop+ 'px',
            'left': finalLeft+'px',
            'width': finalWidth+'px',
        }, 1000, [ 400, 20 ], function(){
            //animate the quick view: animate its width to the final value
            $('.cd-quick-view').addClass('animate-width').velocity({
                'left': quickViewLeft+'px',
                'width': quickViewWidth+'px',
            }, 300, 'ease' ,function(){
                //show quick view content
                $('.cd-quick-view').addClass('add-content');
            });
        }).addClass('is-visible');
    } else {
        //close the quick view reverting the animation
        $('.cd-quick-view').removeClass('add-content').velocity({
            'top': finalTop+ 'px',
            'left': finalLeft+'px',
            'width': finalWidth+'px',
        }, 300, 'ease', function(){
            $('body').removeClass('overlay-layer');
            $('.cd-quick-view').removeClass('animate-width').velocity({
                "top": topSelected,
                "left": leftSelected,
                "width": widthSelected,
            }, 500, 'ease', function(){
                $('.cd-quick-view').removeClass('is-visible');
                parentListItem.removeClass('empty-box');
            });
        });
    }
}
function closeNoAnimation(image, finalWidth, maxQuickWidth) {
    var parentListItem = image.parent('.cd-item'),
        topSelected = image.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(),
        leftSelected = image.offset().left,
        widthSelected = image.width();

    //close the quick view reverting the animation
    $('body').removeClass('overlay-layer');
    parentListItem.removeClass('empty-box');
    $('.cd-quick-view').velocity("stop").removeClass('add-content animate-width is-visible').css({
        "top": topSelected,
        "left": leftSelected,
        "width": widthSelected,
    });
}
});
```

PHP; Simple connect to MySQL code, i think it's unnecessary, to show here, because it get's the right value, and it not the PHP fault, that's is not opening one window with the right content. All values were fine imported.:

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USER", "LOGIN", "DATABSAE");

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    $id = $row['id'];               
?>

<!-- HTML CODE, BUTTON FROM ABOVE -->

<?php
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }

} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Any idea, what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you put the php code rendering this template too.

Comment: Hmm, i think it's unnecessary, but have updated.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this js code:

```
$('.cd-trigger').on('click', function(event){
    var selectedImage = $(this).parent('.cd-item').find('img'),
    selectedImageUrl = selectedImage.attr('src');

    $('body').addClass('overlay-layer');
    $(this).addClass('cd-visible'); // before missing dot in $() operator, now use this to run actions only in current element
    animateQuickView(selectedImage, sliderFinalWidth, maxQuickWidth, 'open');        

    // update the visible slider image in the quick view panel
    // you don't need to implement/use the updateQuickView if 
    // retrieving the quick view data with ajax
    updateQuickView(selectedImageUrl);
});
```

Comment: does it have the same behavior as before?

Comment: Yes. It opens all "popup windows", than one, with the right content.